# Django - Access field by iterating over field list

Tags: python, django

I am storing all many to many fields on an object using this -

```
m2m_fields = list(model_source_obj._meta.many_to_many)
```

I want to iterate over this list to make changes to another object of the same type. I have written the code for it as such -

```
for field in m2m_fields:
    model_target_obj.field.add(**something)
```

However, I keep getting the error model_target_obj class type has no attribute 'field'. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You're not accessing the field, you're accessing the (non-existent) literal attribute called "field".

You could use `getattr`:

```
obj = getattr(model_target_obj, field)
obj.add(**something)
```

But I suspect that there are better ways to do whatever you are trying to do.